# sending mail in PHP not write log file.

Tags: php, sendmail

I am trying to send mail using `PHP` but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am running `Mac OS X Snow Leopard`.

I've tried a simple PHP script using `mail()`, which doesn't write anything to `/var/log/mail.log`

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: No errors? Output in the PHP error log? Is sendmail installed, working and configured?

Comment: The script was supposed to say either meant to say success or failed, script was blank. nothing in /var/log/mail.log its a pretty new installation of Snow Leopard. Isn't sendmail installed by default?

Comment: Can you add your script to your question?

Comment: If you're certain that the mail is actually being sent, you may want to check your spam folder?  I suspect that mail sent by a personal computer isn't super reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, you are unable to send mail from your computer. You need to configure this in the php.ini file using SMTP (perhaps using Gmail). Consider reading this article, it will clarify things:

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1045471.html

The article is a bit extensive, but it should give you a thorough understanding.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Once this happened to me;
What I did was I made it send a mail message via SMTP(gmail account) and that fixed it.
I dont know what caused it, perhaps a lack of an SMTP server. (on my ubuntu computer, but same thing i guess)

Comment: Can this be configured in the php.ini file?

Comment: Another thing to consider, some ISPs will block outgoing mail unless it goes through their mail server.

Comment: @user390426 No, you need to do it seperately. I did it by way of calling a simple python file, but for example: http://www.vulgarisoip.com/?p=17, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page. Good Luck!

Comment: @user390426 Actually, look at Adrian Carroley's answer. it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? 
[PHP, mail() and OSX Leopard](http://jspr.tndy.me/2008/05/php-mail-and-osx-leopard/)

Comment: I followed that, but I'm still at a loss to why mail wont send.

Comment: Can you post your script here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

> sudo postfix start

in Terminal

Comment: That gives: postfix/postfix-script: fatal: the Postfix mail system is already running